# Delete input if date is invalid : XAML datepicker

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker

I am working with datepicker control in silverlight. I want to delete input if date is invalid.

I have tried following code :

XAML:

```
<sdk:DatePicker Height="23" x:Name="datePicker1" Width="179" 
                DateValidationError="datePicker1_DateValidationError"  />
```

C#:

```
private void datePicker1_DateValidationError(object sender, DatePickerDateValidationErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (datePicker1.SelectedDate != null && (Regex.IsMatch(datePicker1.SelectedDate.ToString(), @"^([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2])[- / .]([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])[- / .](1[9][0-9][0-9]|2[0][0-9][0-9])$")))
            {
              //WORKING FINE
            }
                else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid date");
                DatePicker myElement = ((FrameworkElement)System.Windows.Application.Current.RootVisual).FindName("datePicker1") as DatePicker;    // search for control named "datePicker1"

                myElement.Text = String.Empty;

            }
         }
        catch
         {

         }
 }
```

But myElement returns null and I can not delete invalid input.

Comment: `datePicker1` is DatePicker control. How can it be `DatePickerTextBox`?

Comment: @RohitVats : ok, Edited code for that but still not working. It is setting value again and I dont know from where :(

Comment: I have added an answer. See if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code I used to do a similar thing:

Code behind:

```
private void DatePicker_DateValidationError(object sender, DatePickerDateValidationErrorEventArgs e)
        {

            var MyDatePicker = sender as DatePicker;

            DatePickerTextBox dateBox = MyDatePicker.GetVisualDescendants().OfType<DatePickerTextBox>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (dateBox != null)
            {
                dateBox.Text = String.Empty;
            }
            // clear the SelectedDate property too, otherwise you'll be left with the last valid one
            MyDatePicker.SelectedDate = null;
        }
```

Xaml:

```
<sdk:DatePicker DateValidationError="DatePicker_DateValidationError"/>
```

I have a number of pickers all on the same form, and all sharing this DateValidationError handler, hence not finding the picker by name.

Answer (score 0):

No need to search for `datePicker1` if you have set `x:Name` already on it. You can access directly it in code behind:

```
datePicker1.Text = String.Empty;
```

Moreover, if it's part of some template which is restricting you from accessing it, it is **already passed in you method as sender object**. You can get it like this:

```
DatePicker myElement = (DatePicker)sender;
myElement.Text = String.Empty;
```